# unable to install packages using dpkg on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dpkg

Getting following error

```
> sudo dpkg -i chefdk_4.7.73-1_amd64.deb
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: incorrect data check'
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive chefdk_4.7.73-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 chefdk_4.7.73-1_amd64.deb
```

> I have updated the output

```
shasum -a 256 /path/to/chefdk_4.7.73-1_amd64.deb
shasum: /path/to/chefdk_4.7.73-1_amd64.deb:
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1229746/edit) your question and add the output of `shasum -a 256 /path/to/chefdk_4.7.73-1_amd64.deb`. Please also tell us which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: @mook765  I have updated the output, please have a look

Comment: @above `/path/to/` refers to the location where your file is; which is likely in `/home/yourusername/Downloads/` or `/home/yourusername`

Comment: I am new to this I am using ubuntu through vagrant. How can I do that

Comment: @SnehalDwivedi `shasum -a 256 chefdk_4.7.73-1_amd64.deb` should also work if the file is located in the current directory. Open file manager and navigate to the folder containing the package, right click and choose "Open in terminal". Run the above command. Also, please mention the Ubuntu version you're using and the site from where you downloaded the package.

Comment: @Kulfy  ```shasum -a 256 chefdk_4.7.73-1_amd64.deb``` command is working following is the  result ```2de8f8e95a651869a2b68f020dd01a5dcdadb53f212b3cab4f9cc6c6d2c38f13  chefdk_4.7.73-1_amd64.deb``` 
I require a solution for dpkg not installing my package

Comment: @SnehalDwivedi The mentioned SHA256SUM doesn't match with any package listed [here](https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk/). The package might have been corrupted while downloading. Try downloading and installation again.

Comment: @Kulfy because I have tried to download another

Comment: I tried downloading 4 different debs of chefdk from [here](https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk/) and the SHASUM I got is same as they listed on their site. Try changing the network if the package is getting corrupted every time you download that.